# How to pass user id and pwd in oauth 2.0 for grant_type=password?

Tags: oauth

How to pass authorization of base 64 code for grant type = password in oauth 2.0 or user id and pwd in oauth 2.0.

I am passing like this still its not working

```
String reqString = granttype+"&"+clientid+"&"+username+"&"+password;

getTrace().addInfo("Request: "+reqString); inputStream = (InputStream) new ByteArrayInputStream(reqString.getBytes()); getTrace().addInfo("InputStream: "+ inputStream);

com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.Payload payload = LookupService.getXmlPayload(inputStream);
getTrace().addInfo("Payload: "+ payload);

com.sap.aii.mapping.lookup.Payload result = accessor.call(payload);
getTrace().addInfo("Result: "+ result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass all the information in the form of query string.

```
baseurl + "grant_type=password&username=<username>&password=<password>&client_id=<client id>"
```

E.g.

```
"https://oauthservice.com/oauth2/default/v1/token?grant_type=password&username=rabin&password=password123&client_id=MTQ0NjOkZmQ5OTM5NDE9ZTZjNGZmZjI3"
```

You can also specify scope in the query string by adding `&scope=openid`

Comment: Its giving me HTTP 405 Method not allowed

Comment: Are you sending a GET request? If yes, you have to make it post.

Comment: Nope using post method only,,

Comment: Do you have access to the documentation or something similar of the identity provider? It looks like either your IDP accepts different HTTP verb for the request or your URL construction is not correct.